# Retrofit, response body sempre null mas no servidor é status 200

Tags: android, json, rest, retrofit, okhttp

Estou implementando um aplicativo Android utilizando Retrofit 2, o service é genérico o do lado servidor está funcionando.

O problema é: O response.body() vem sempre nulo, nunca consigo pegar o json, mesmo conseguindo imprimir ele com o OKHTTP.

Como resolver este problema ou pegar o json direto do okhttp?

**ServiceGenerator**

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {

        //Instancia do interceptador das requisições
        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor);


        //Instância do retrofit
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

**RetrofirServicesPost**

```
public interface RetrofitServicePost {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @GET("tipoalerta")
    Call<List<TipoAlerta>> getListaTipoAlerta();

    @GET("tipoalerta/id/{id}")
    Call<TipoAlerta> getTipoAlerta(@Path("id") String id);

(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta, era um erro simples. O ServiveGenerator foi construído para esperar como resposta uma lista, foi só mudar a construção da requisição e tudo funcionou corretamente.

**RetrofitServices**

```
    public interface RetrofitServicePost {

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @GET("tipoalerta")
        Call<List<TipoAlerta>> getListaTipoAlerta();

        @FormUrlEncoded
        @GET("tipoalerta/id/{id}")
        Call<List<TipoAlerta>> getTipoAlerta(@Path("id") String id);

    (...)
    }
```